# Vagrant-Vsphere plugin issues

Tags: ruby, vagrant

I need any help i can get on this. I'm using vagrant 1.5 with the sphere plugin 1.0.1 but everytime i vagrant up, i get the error message below. I have looked everywhere and still can't figure it it. Can anyone help please?

```
 INFO runner: Running action: #<Vagrant::Action::Builder:0x007f87c0f2f6d0>
ERROR vagrant: Vagrant experienced an error! Details:
ERROR vagrant: #<VagrantPlugins::VSphere::Errors::VSphereError: undefined method `communicator' for #<VagrantPlugins::Kernel_V2::VMConfig:0x00000000de5800>>
ERROR vagrant: undefined method `communicator' for #<VagrantPlugins::Kernel_V2::VMConfig:0x00000000de5800>
ERROR vagrant: /root/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/vagrant-vsphere-1.0.1/lib/vSphere/action/connect_vsphere.rb:23:in `rescue in call'
/root/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/vagrant-vsphere-1.0.1/lib/vSphere/action/connect_vsphere.rb:14:in `call'
/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.5.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.5.2/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/config_validate.rb:25:in `call'
/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.5.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.5.2/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/handle_box.rb:56:in `call'
/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.5.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.5.2/lib/vagrant/action/builder.rb:116:in `call'
/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.5.2/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:69:in `block in run'
/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.5.2/lib/vagrant/util/busy.rb:19:in `busy'
/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.5.2/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:69:in `run'
/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.5.2/lib/vagrant/machine.rb:157:in `action'
/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.5.2/lib/vagrant/batch_action.rb:72:in `block (2 levels) in run'
 INFO interface: error: undefined method `communicator' for #<VagrantPlugins::Kernel_V2::VMConfig:0x00000000de5800>
undefined method `communicator' for #<VagrantPlugins::Kernel_V2::VMConfig:0x00000000de5800>
```

Answer (score 0):

Vagrant-vSphere 1.0.1 requires Vagrant 1.6.4 or newer.

See: https://github.com/nsidc/vagrant-vsphere